# Per capita surface area for (car) transport since WWII

Tags: data-request, historical, transportation

It is an obvious phenomenon that the surface area each person 'requires' for transport has been increasing over the past decades (with growing wealth), because we have more cars.

I'm interested in the actual figures since the second World War.
How much surface area per person is taken up by roads, parking spaces, etc. In 1950, 1960, etcetera?

Notes:

- I'm only asking for cars because I think the space taken by other forms of transport is very small in comparison
- I'm especially interested in Europe or my country, the Netherlands, but do not exclude other regions
- Any data format is fine
- Related: [A similar question for living space](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13463/per-capita-surface-area-for-living-since-wwii).